# How to avoid error when using Eloquent's toArray when getting null result

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7

l am getting start at a new laravel project with 5.7, but one problem, when l use `first()` to fetch data, and if data is not exist, it will return `null`, and then execute `toArray()` will throw a PHP error. So l use follow code to reslove it.

```
$user_model = \App\Model\User::where('id', $id);

if ($select) {
    $user_model->select(explode(',', $select));
}

$user_data = $user_model->first();
$user_data = $user_data ?? $user_data->toArray();
```

So is there any better way?

Comment: Can you show the code where you're using `$user_data`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Any one of the following will work, each providing their own way of dealing with a null result:

**1. [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-optional) helper:**

> The optional function accepts any argument and allows you to access 
>   properties or call methods on that object. If the given object is null, 
>   properties and methods will return null instead of causing an error.

```
$user_data = optional($user_model->first())->toArray();
```

**2. [firstOr()](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_firstOr):**

> Execute the query and get the first result or call a callback.

```
$data = User::where('id', $id)->when(!is_null($select), function ($query) use ($select) {
    return $query->select(explode(',', $select));
})->firstOr(function () {
    return ['message' => 'No results'];
});
```

**3. [rescue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-rescue) helper:**

> The rescue function executes the given Closure and catches any exceptions that occur during its execution. All exceptions that are caught will be sent to your exception handler's report method; however, the request will continue processing.

```
$data = rescue(function () use ($select) {
    \App\Model\User::where('id', $id);

    if ($select) {
        $user_model->select(explode(',', $select));
    }

    return $user_model->first()->toArray();
});
```

**4. try catch:**

```
try {
    $user_model = \App\Model\User::where('id', $id);

    if ($select) {
        $user_model->select(explode(',', $select));
    }

    $user_data = $user_model->first();
    $user_data = $user_data ?? $user_data->toArray();
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    // handle the exception...
}
```

Comment: So, there is not some way to prevent this error by chained call? For example, l might build a long sql like `OneModel::where(xx,xx)->orWhere(xx,xx)-> ....(long sql)->first()->toArray()`. and l must to split this statement like this `$model = OneModel::...(long sql)->first();  $model=optional($model)->toArray();` ?

Comment: You can wrap the entire chain `optional(OneModel::where(...)...->first())->toArray()`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel provides a `firstOrFail` method which throws an 404 Exception by default.

```
    $user_data = $user_model->firstOrFail(); // If not found an exception is thrown and will be handled by default ExceptionHandler which displays a 404 error page. 
    // if found, cast the User to array
    $user_data = $user_data->toArray();
```

Comment: l don't want to throw a 404 error by laravel. l want to controller this by myself